# import xml into another xml

Tags: android, xml

I have lots of control repeated in my `xml` (a `Button` for instance). Is there any possibility to write the `Button` once in a `xml` and then import it in all the layout I need it?

Comment: I faced this issue when I was going to make top bar that looks like nav bar of iOS.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use

```
<include  layout="@layout/commonlayout" android:id="@+id/id" />
```

`commonlayout.xml` should be defined in `res/layout` where you can add the repeated parts.

Answer (score 26):

As **Labeeb P** rightly said, it works. 
Just want to add that you can also override parameters too:

```
<include  
        layout="@layout/commonlayout" 
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2sp"
 />
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to those great answers, you can also avoid code duplication by using the `<merge>` tag, like so:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/delete"/>

</merge>
```

The `<merge>` part gets stripped when you include it into other xml. This might help including more than a single `Button` at a time. See the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default `include` XML tag to include an external layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/somelayout" />
```

This layout should have an outside `ViewGroup` that encapsulates the content or a `merge` tag to avoid having to use an unnecessary layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- OR -->

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</merge>
```

Also, if you need a better way to include pieces of layout that acts like a container (a custom `ViewGroup`), you can use this [custom ViewGroup](https://github.com/mauriciogior/IncludeView). Note that this does not import an XML into another XML file, it inflates the content from the external layout and replaces into the view. It's similar to `ViewStub`, a "ViewGroupStub" like.

This lib acts as if the `ViewStub` could be used as following (**note that this example does not work! `ViewStub` isn't a `ViewGroup` subclass!**):

```
<ViewStub layout="@layout/somecontainerlayout" 
    inflate_inside="@+id/somecontainerid">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</ViewStub>
```