# how to split main.xml to other xmls?

Tags: android

I have main.xml and is a very large file, i want to split some of the components(some layouts) to other xml so that i can link from main.xml itself. is this possible from android ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [import xml into another xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132362/import-xml-into-another-xml)

Answer (score 10):

You can use this

```
<include  layout="@layout/commonlayout" android:id="@+id/id" />
```

Refer this [import xml into another xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132362/import-xml-into-another-xml/4132452#4132452)