# Is it possible to inherit the attributes of a xml file?

Tags: android, xml

For example, when creating list items, I would like to reuse Android's `simple_list_item1.xml` or `simple_list_item2.xml`, but I would also like to tweak them.

So, is there any method to inherit the attributes of these views that are declared in xml?

My solution for now is to copy all the attributes in `simple_list_item1.xml` to a self-defined style, then have the TextView inherit the style. But I hope to get the data directly from android so that if things changes in the future, my views also inherits the changes.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132362/import-xml-into-another-xml/4132452#4132452. They include custom layouts and also modify them

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to use inheritance in a OOP model. The best way to use this is to copy and paste the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) into your own project.