# Sidebar in each activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

For an application I am designing we have to deal with some "special" needs of our users. One of these is to create a navigation sidebar that has to appear in almost all the activities.

This navigation bar has to contain always the same three buttons that links to three activities: HOME, INFO, CONFIGURATION.

Each of these three activities can also load others activities that can (or cannot) contain this navigation bar.
Each of these buttons has to reset the current activity-stack status bringing to the top the corresponding activity selected by the user.

The navigation bar has to be customisable (made visible/invisible) and I would like also to deactivate some of the buttons.

**EDIT:** It has to be similar to a Drawer, but the buttons have to be highly customisable (in size and appearance) and it has to be always on (no sliding functions).

What is the best way to achieve that without manually including those buttons in each of my layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this layout manually but only once - in your `ActivityBase` class. Other activities can extend this base class.

**EDIT:**

As I said, I'm improving my answer.
So my idea is to create an `Activity` with menu. And if other `Activity` needs to have the same menu it can extend this `ActivityBase` and add it's own layout.
Let's look on a simple example.

`ActivityBase` layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I created a simple layout that contains **menu bar** and a **container** for layout from Activities that will be extending `AcivityBase`.

Now `ActivityBase`:

```
public class ActivityBase extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
    }


}
```

It's a simple `Activity`, but if you want, you can also place here menu events handling if they are the same for all Activities that will be extending this.

And now let's see at `SecondActivity's` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

It's a normal layout, nothing special. I put some controls in there just for purpose of this example.

And `SecondActivity` class:

```
public class SecondActivity extends MainActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_activity, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container));
    }


}
```

It extends `ActivityBase` and what is important - it **does not** call `setContentView`. Instead we are creating `LayoutInflater` and we are inflating `second_activity` layout in the `container` that we created in `activity_base` layout.

Comment: OK. Then I can use this layout as my base for others Activities?
Do you mind including a small example, or a link to one resource that contains an example?

(_As side information:_ I already extended the `Activity` class to create a customised `MyActivity` that contains some utilities that I need in every screen of my application).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the archive. I was thinking more about some few lines or a blog post that also other people may find useful.
Is that link going to expire?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would post it as an answer but I'm at work now so I don't have much time. I will do it when I get home :)

Comment: I read the XML and understood the concept. I will try implementing it. As soon as you'll extend the answer I'll mark it as Answered.

Comment: It works like a charm. I can eventually write my own methods in the extended `MainActivity` class so as to handle different events (click), and different configurations (deactivate/remove buttons). Thanks for you update.

Comment: You could also use a custom view or just externalize these elements and use <include>

Comment: At the end, I've never succeed doing that method, so I've tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132362/import-xml-into-another-xml the code isn't shared, so you'll need to factorise differently the answer to click in the common bar, but it's more debuggable...